# ASP.NET MVC Sybase IQ 15

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, sap-iq

I am attempting to connect to my company's database which is Sybase IQ 15.4.
I am using MVC 5 EF 6, every connection string I find on http://www.connectionstrings.com/
does not work (or at least I have not been able to get it to work) 
I thought I had a way around it with going through DSN but it appears EF does not work with DSN. Is there anyone out there that knows if 1) it is possible to connect to Sybase IQ through EF. 2) How to go about setting up the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem one year ago, there was no possibility to connect. But maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: Darn I was really hoping that this would have had a resolution by now. I really figured Microsoft would have come up with a fix for this issue.